# Font size doesn't decrease size of my program

Tags: fonts

I'm creating an android application for someone that gathers information about his clients and their transactions. His device is quite old so he asked if I could decrease the size of the program.

I tried to do this using the simplest possible algorithm which is to make the font size smaller. I tried this and compiled my program but it didn't change in size, not even a single byte.

This is my output

```
total 18228
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mark mark 18665472 May  2 15:27 ClientTransactions.jar
```

I changed the font of my program from **12pt** to **8pt**

The new output is:

```
total 18228
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mark mark 18665472 May  2 15:29 ClientTransactions.jar
```

Can anyone help me further with this, i'm really confused

Comment: Surely the only way to change the weight of the app would be to remove characters from the font set? The actual pixel size of the rendered text will have no effect.

Comment: if decreasing font size starts to reduce program size... then size of data would contribute in weight of hard disk drive... :-|

Comment: I don't mean the size of the rendered text. I changed the font size of my source code but it doesn't have any effects whatsoever. I just changed the size of my program's font as well and it's still 18665472 MB

Comment: I would recommend to minify your code by removing unnecessary white spaces/breaks in the program.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I even removed comments but the actual size of the program remains the same for some strange reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the font size of your source code has no effect on it's size.
Compiling it will result in the same size every time.

Try to refactor your code and get rid of any unused methods,...

Comment: But unused methods won't change the program size either. Would you take a hammer to work when you're a programmer? Well the compiler won't put unused methods in your program either, right?

Comment: The compiler isn't that smart. Any unused methods, classes, and so on will be compiled as well. Check your code and remove those you don't use.